# SSMA Access console to migrate password protected accessdb to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, migration

I'm trying to migrate Access database tables to SQL Server using SSMA and it works fine if my MS Access database is not password protected but fails to prompt for password when it is password protected. It throws error message as follows

> INPUT Enter password for **.accdb
> WARNING SSMA Schema Collector component “Access Object Collector” reported an error
> Description: An error occurred while loading database information
> Exception: The handle is invalid